# Why might requestFocusInWindow() fail?

Tags: java, swing, focus

My Java swing app calls requestFocusInWindow() on a component.  The component is focusable, visible, and enabled.  It's parent is visible.  Yet requestFocusInWindow() returns false and the focus goes elsewhere.  If I tab around I get to the desired component and there is no problem with it gaining focus.

Why would requestFocusInWindow() fail under such circumstances?

(Please don't suggest a simple test program.  I'm sure I would not have this problem in such a case.  What I am looking for is a debugging strategy for a complex situation where this problem exists).

Here is a code fragment:

```
public void setFormFocus() {
    log.trace("BillingForm.setFormFocus()");
            // sets latest enablement status of each field
    updateFieldEditability();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(fwdNumberFocus);
};
```

...

```
 private Runnable fwdNumberFocus= new Runnable() {
     public void run() {        
         log.trace("fwdNumberFocus.run()");
         if (!fwdNumberField.hasFocus()) {
             if (fwdNumberField.requestFocusInWindow() == false){
                 log.debugf("fwdNumberField visible: %s, focusable: %s, enabled: %s", fwdNumberField.isVisible(), fwdNumberField.isFocusable(), fwdNumberField.isEnabled());
                 focusOnFirstFocusableItem();
             }
             else{
                 log.debug("fwdNumberField focus gained");
             }
         }
     }
 };
```

When this executes the log statement in fwdNumberFocus appears as

> fwdNumberField visible: true, focusable: true, enabled: true

From the code, this would only be executed if requestFocusInWindow() failed.

What I am expecting to see in the log is

> fwdNumberField focus gained

but I don't.  If the field is visible, focusable, and enabled, why would this fail?

Comment: IIRC requestFocusInWindow() will fail if the window containing the component is not active.

Answer (score 1):

OK, false alarm.  Problem was due to some convoluted code.  This form lives in a JTabbedPane and in this particular circumstance somehow the tab index was not being set, but something else made the form visible later.  At the moment when the focus decision was being made, the form wasn't visible or focusable.

Somehow, the analysis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810777/what-causes-component-requestfocus-to-fail-sometimes?rq=1), enabled me to see that.

Probably, my updateFieldEditability() method above should have checked that the parent was also visible, enabled and focusable before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

> What I am looking for is a debugging strategy

You probably have some code in your Event Listener that is manipulating focus and is overriding your focus request.

Try wrapping your requestFocusInWindow() statement in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() so that your code gets added to the end of EDT after all other events have been handled.

Comment: I've added more detail to the question.  As you can see, I am wrapping my method in invokeLater() and am stumped as to why it would not be working.

Comment: Also, there IS a FocusListener in the fwdNumberField but it does nothing to manipulate the focus.